# How do I make baked ambient occlusion surfaces appear white instead of gray?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, texture-baking

I baked an ambient occlusion map of a model but the main surfaces appear gray. I would like them to appear white so that I can multiply the ambient occlusion map with a texture map that I make.

**How can I bake ambient occlusion maps where a flat surface appears white rather than gray?**

Here is a picture of the model which appears gray:

[image: Model]

Here is the AO map which shows the gray:

[image: Lightmap]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This depends on the diffuse color of your object.
Make sure the color is set to white and the intensity is set to 1 before baking:

[image]

Result:

[image]